# Redirect to another page after submitting a form?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, submission

I'm trying to redirect users to another page after a form has been submitted. The form works great. If forces users to input the required fields, and is not submitted unless each of these fields are complete. It then submits the form and refreshes. But I would like to redirect users to another page instead of simply refreshing the page.

My php code is below!

```
<?php

$recipients = 'dre@myemail.com';
//$recipients = '#';

try {
require './phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

preg_match_all("/([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]   {2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)/", $recipients, $addresses, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

if (!count($addresses[0])) {
    die('MF001');
}

if (preg_match('/^(127\.|192\.168\.)/', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    die('MF002');
}

$template = file_get_contents('rd-mailform1.tpl');

if (isset($_POST['form-type'])) {
    switch ($_POST['form-type']){
        case 'registration':
            $subject = 'New Registration';
            break;
        case 'subscribe':
            $subject = 'Subscribe request';
            break;
        case 'order':
            $subject = 'Order request';
            break;
        default:
            $subject = 'A message from your site visitor';
            break;
    }
}else{
    die('MF004');
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $template = str_replace(
        ["<!-- #{FromState} -->", "<!-- #{FromEmail} -->"],
        ["Email:", $_POST['email']],
        $template);
}else{
    die('MF003');
}

if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $template = str_replace(
        ["<!-- #{MessageState} -->", "<!-- #{MessageDescription} -->"],
        ["Message:", $_POST['message']],
        $template);
}

preg_match("/(<!-- #{BeginInfo} -->)(.|\n)+(<!-- #{EndInfo} -->)/", $template, $tmp, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != "email" && $key != "message" && $key != "form-type" && !empty($value)){
        $info = str_replace(
            ["<!-- #{BeginInfo} -->", "<!-- #{InfoState} -->", "<!-- #{InfoDescription} -->"],
            ["", ucfirst($key) . ':', $value],
            $tmp[0][0]);

        $template = str_replace("<!-- #{EndInfo} -->", $info, $template);
    }
}

$template = str_replace(
    ["<!-- #{Subject} -->", "<!-- #{SiteName} -->"],
    [$subject, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']],
    $template);

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$mail->FromName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

foreach ($addresses[0] as $key => $value) {
    $mail->addAddress($value[0]);
}

$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($template);

if (isset($_FILES['attachment'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['attachment']['error'] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$key],    $_FILES['Attachment']['name'][$key]);
        }
    }
}

$mail->send();

die('MF000');
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
die('MF254');
} catch (Exception $e) {
die('MF255');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect the page.  Where ever you determine that the form's action was successfully executed, add this:

```
header('Location: path/to/your/file.php');  //Could also be an external or internal URL
```